# Start 2 VENVs and 2 Python programs from 1 Batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, service

I have 2 python programs that act as 'services', each of them runs from its own venv. I'm looking to create a batch file to initiate both services, each on their own dedicated terminal.

I was able to create 1 batch file to initiate the venv and the service, but I cant merge them into one batch file.

```
CALL <PATH_TO_VENV_SCRIPTS>\activate
"<PATH_TO_PYTHON_FILE>main.py"
pause
```

When I run the file above, a terminal opens, activates the venv, and runs the main.py using the venv.

Now I'm trying to have 1 batch to start both services. I have the following:

```
START <PATH_TO_VENV1_ACTIVATE.BAT>
"<PATH_TO_SERVICE1_PYTHON_FILE>main.py"

START <PATH_TO_VENV2_ACTIVATE.BAT>
"<PATH_TO_SERVICE2_PYTHON_FILE>main.py"
```

The file above indeed opens 2 terminals, and activates both VENVs, but unfortunatelly the python files are initiated from a third terminal which opens before the aforementioned 2.

How can I get the python files to be initiated from their own VENV terminal?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your question "How can I make the path files...?", is it a typo and you actually meant "batch files"?

Comment: Typo, sorry. I meant the following: 
How can I get the python files to be initiated from their own VENV terminal?

Comment: Have you tried, `Start "VEnv1" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C "Call "<PATH_TO_VENV1_SCRIPT>\activate.bat" & "<PATH_TO_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE>\python.exe" "<PATH_TO_SERVICE1_PYTHON_FILE>\main.py""` followed by, `Start "VEnv2" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C "Call "<PATH_TO_VENV2_SCRIPT>\activate.bat" & "<PATH_TO_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE>\python.exe" "<PATH_TO_SERVICE2_PYTHON_FILE>\main.py""`. _Depending upon your requirements, you may wish to change `/C` to `/K`._

Comment: Compo, that worked beautifully. I modified it slightly:
```Start "Service1" cmd.exe /d /c "CALL "<PATH_TO_ACTIVATE.BAT>" & "<PATH_TO_PYTHON_MAIN.PY>""```

Rinse and repeart for service2.
Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose, that's fine too @RodrigoBastos, it's just that my preference is to specifically ask python.exe to run a .py file, instead of relying upon the system and any of its configurable or easily broken settings to take time to try to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to launch your python files as a command in your newly created venv terminal. If you start the python service from the parent script, they're executed in this terminal context.

In other words: You have to include the execution of the scripts into your *PATH_TO_VENV1_ACTIVATE.BAT*. However, if your python script does not terminate after execution, you won't ever get there and the "parent" terminal will hang on the first script. So make sure that the script runs in a way which does not block the parent calling context.

HTH

EDIT: If your scripts are starting a service anyway, consider creating a container and launch these from there. Therefore you have an encapsulated context paired with easy execution.

Comment: Container as in docker and stuff?
Unfortunatelly that's not available in my current environment, but will consider it for future projects.